# python shared memory with pool

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I am trying to use the shared_memory with pool in python's multiprocessing.

In the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory), about `shared memory`, the argument `buf` (the memory view) is not clear to me (perhaps because I don't understand the concept of memory view - is it a pointer?).
I want to use this shared memory across different processes. Following, my example base on the documentation:

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8])  
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=a.nbytes)

# Do I need to create the existing_shm or I can keep using shm?
existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm.name)
```

Now comes my first problem. I define the function that will use the array in the shared memory:

```
def test_function(Input):
    c = np.ndarray(a.shape, dtype=np.int64, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
    c[1]=100
    print(c)
```

This is incorrect but I don't know how should it be.

Then the main. Is there a role of having the main function to make this work?

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    with Pool(os.cpu_count()) as p:
        p.map(test_function, range(12))
```

It doesn't work.
Do I have to define `c` in every process? Or I can define it in the main and use it across all processes? I assume that `c` is a python object and therefore can't be shared by processes due to the gil-lock?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. I don't have a clear understanding of all the facts yet, though.

1- The shared memory object is declared:
`shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=10000000*4)`.

2- A (numpy array in this case) object is declared with buffer as follows:
`b = np.ndarray((10000000,), dtype=np.int32, buffer=shm.buf)`.

3- The numpy array is populated by copying data into it.
 `b[:] = np.random.randint(100, size=10000000, dtype=np.int32)`.

Then, all the function to be executed in many cpus needs is the name of the shared memory object and the mentioned step 2 inside the function is mapping the shared memory, which has been populated earlier.

It's essential that you `close` the shared object after accessing it and at the end `unlink`.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory, Pool
import os


def test_function(args): 
    Input, shm_name, size = args
    existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm_name)
    d = np.ndarray(size, dtype=np.int32, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
    #print(Input, d[Input-1:Input+2])
    d[Input]=-20
    #print(Input, d[Input-1:Input+2])
    existing_shm.close()
    print(Input, 'parent process:', os.getppid())
    print(Input, 'process id:', os.getpid())


if __name__=='__main__':
    
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=10000000*4)
    b = np.ndarray((10000000,), dtype=np.int32, buffer=shm.buf)
    b[:] = np.random.randint(100, size=10000000, dtype=np.int32)

    inputs =[[    1,shm.name,b.shape],
    [    2,shm.name,b.shape],
    [    3,shm.name,b.shape],
    [    4,shm.name,b.shape],
    [    5,shm.name,b.shape],
    [    6,shm.name,b.shape],
    [    7,shm.name,b.shape],
    [    8,shm.name,b.shape],
    [    9,shm.name,b.shape],
    [    10,shm.name,b.shape],
    [    11,shm.name,b.shape],
    [    12,shm.name,b.shape],
    [13,shm.name,b.shape]]

    with Pool(os.cpu_count()) as p:
        p.map(test_function, inputs)
 
    print(b[:20])
    
    # Clean up from within the first Python shell
    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()  # Free and release the shared memory block at the very end
```

Comment: the docs also give a great way to get the size needed for a particular numpy array `myndarray.nbytes`. There is also a manager but its fairly rudimentary